# Read matching csv rows into List<Dictionary>

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I am trying to read the header row of a structured csv file, find rows matching a parameter, then return matched rows as a list of dictionary objects as List[Dictionary[Header, RowColumnValue]].

I want to be able to assign List[x][key] Dictionary values to controls in a form.

The below is basically pseudo-code as it doesn't work, but hopefully the idea is clear. I assume there is a way to simplify this via LINQ:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> RowEntries(string LocationAndCategory)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv");
    var header = lines.First().Split(',');          
    List<string> rowsList = lines
        .Where(line => line.Split(',')[0] + " " + line.Split(',')[1] == LocationAndCategory)
        .Select(line => line).ToList();
    int y = 0;
    var listDictionaries = new { List<Dictionary<string, string>>};
    foreach(string line in rowsList)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= header.Count<string>(); x++)
        {
            listDictionaries.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>);
            listDictionaries[y].Add(header[x], Split(rowsList[y], (','))[x]);
        }
        y++;
    }
    return listDictionaries;
}
```

Comment: The question is how to split each row into a dictionary right?

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ you can do this way :

```
var result = lines
    .Skip(1)    //skip the header line
    .Where(line => line.Split(',')[0] + " " + line.Split(',')[1] == LocationAndCategory)

    //project the query to an enumerable of dictionary of (header,value)
    .Select(line => header.Select((h, i) => new { header = h, index = i })
                          .ToDictionary(o => o.header, o => line.Split(',')[o.index]))
    .ToList();
```

And here is a more query style version of the above :

```
var result = (from line in lines.Skip(1)
              let cols = line.Split(',')
              where cols[0] + " " + cols[1] == LocationAndCategory
              select
                header.Select((h, i) => new { header = h, index = i })
                      .ToDictionary(o => o.header, o => cols[o.index])
              ).ToList();
```

Comment: Fantastic, both of these work perfectly! I wish I could award the answer to everyone who helped; I gave it to @HariPrasad only because he was a bit quicker. I do find your solutions slightly more comprehensible and readable.

Comment: @xnguyeng Hint, to see answer in the order it posted (oldest on top), make sure you have 'oldest' tab selected (on the top right of Answers section) :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I understand that you need each row in `CSV` to convert as  `Dictionary`.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> RowEntries(string LocationAndCategory)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv");
    var header = lines.First().Split(',');          
    int y=-1;

    return lines.Skip(1) //skip header.
                // Split string and take only first two strings to compare with LocationAndCategory.
                .Where(line => string.Join(" ",line.Split(',').Take(2)) == LocationAndCategory) 
                // Split each line by ',' and convert to dictionary.
                .Select(l=>l.Split(',').ToDictionary(x=> header[(++y)%header.Count()], x=>x))
                .ToList();      
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code works perfectly. Can you please explain what the .Where section is doing? I am not clear on 'string.Join(" "...' and 'Take(2). Also I have never seen the '%header' usage. In any event I will award you the answer as your code works and you were first. I will also take a look at @har07's answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @xnguyeng I added the description, for each extension please check.

Comment: `String.join` joins an array of elements with the specified delimiter. So code takes first 2 words in each line and joins them with space and compare with `LocationandCategory`.